# Adding view dynamically which keeps margin between two child?

Tags: android

I am unable to set margin between two child view which are linear layout
When i give margin in XML file it doesn't show any changes

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can make chat screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activity_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/message_bar" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/message_field"
            android:hint="Write here"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/send_button"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:listSelector="#00000000" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyChatMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/main_empty_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now to add message programmatically call following method

```
void addNewMessage(Message m) {
        messages.add(m);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
            }
        }, 100l);
    }
```